# Embedding Python in Qt GUI App Windows Issue

Tags: python, c++, windows, qt

Currently, I am developing a C++ GUI application using the Qt framework. Typically this application is driven by user mouse/keyboard input. However, we have recently built a python interface using PyQt so users can drive the application with simple python scripts. This means that we have to embed a python interpreter within our C++ application. In order to initialize the interpreter, we have simply been calling Py_Initialize() in our main.cpp function after setting up the main window and then calling Py_Finalize(); before the program exits. This seems to work without issues on both Mac and Linux platforms, but I seem to be running into problems on windows.

After Py_Initialize() has been called, user’s can open a file browser to pick a file of interest to read into the program. In the code, we use the QFileDialog::getOpenFileName static method to allow users to pick their file. However, on Windows, the program is crashing on this call. The program looks to be crashing on a call to PyDict_GetItem within the python library.

I created a super simple Qt GUI program that also exhibits the same crash. Essentially, the program is a basic Qt GUI application with a single push button in the middle of the main window. When the push button is pressed, a file dialog should appear, but instead the program crashes. The main parts of the code are below.

main.cpp

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    Py_Initialize();
    int result = a.exec();
    Py_Finalize();
    return result;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     QString defaultFileName = QString::fromStdString("file.txt");
     QString getFileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Load File", defaultFileName, "Files (*.txt *.csv)");
}
```

Note that the program is crashing when QFileDialog::getOpenFileName is called after the sole button in the program is pressed.

Here are some additional specs that may be useful for diagnosing the problem:

- Qt Framework Version: Qt 5.4.0
- Python Version: 2.7.10
- Building with Desktop Qt 5.4.0 MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit Kit

Comment: I have all of those installed. Please share your simple GUI app's complete code to repro the issue on my end and help.

Comment: Sorry I am unfamiliar with how I can share. I would love send you the code just not sure how I do that.

Comment: I have posted the code here: https://github.com/ewferg/python-windows-crash

Comment: Let me clarify my request. Make a small proof-of-concept sample program that triggers this error. Grabbing the whole repo at git is a little overkill...

Then, just edit this question, Copy & Paste it in, and then highlight the code and click the **{ }** button to mark it up as code

Comment: Ok, I updated the question. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You need to post something that a user can copy and paste, and be good to go. It helps the rest of us when you remove the guess-work so we can focus on the bug, not getting the test in the same failing state as you. I'm familiar with using PyQt for python apps using Qt, not using it for C++. I don't know how to set up the environment the way you have. Since this appears to be an OS issue, if we can repro it outside of C++ (or not) that helps a ton to narrow down if it's Windows, Qt, or incorrect implementation within C++.